# Undefined Reference to a global array while linking the library

Tags: c, linker, global-variables, shared-libraries

I am having a main file which i am building with a shared library `libhtml`, `libhtml` is build using another shared library `libctpe`. I get no errors/warning when i build both `libctpe` and `libhtml` but when linking the main file with `libhtml` I get the following error,I get the following warning :

`/home/krajput/parser/back_up/15_5/parser/ctpe/libctpe.so`: undefined reference to 
`state_info_table`

Now, Libctpe contains the file ctpe.c where "`state_info_table`" which is a global array of structure pointers is declared globally and then defined using the function `create_state_table()`.

```
State_t **state_info_table;

void create_state_table() {
  int i; 
  State_t **state_info_table = malloc(state_table_size *sizeof(State_t*));
  if(!state_info_table) {
    printf("\nMemroy Allcoation failed\n");
  }  
  for ( i=0;i<state_table_size;i++) {
    state_info_table[i] = malloc(1*sizeof(State_t*));
    state_info_table[i] = NULL;
  }
  return;
}
```

I am not using this array anywhere except this file.Also when i try and do "`nm libctpe.s`" then it shows `state_info_table` as U (undefined symbol).I'm at a loss as to what the issue could be.

Comment: `State_t **state_info_table = malloc(state_table_size *sizeof(State_t*));` declares a local variable whose name shadows the file-scope name.

Comment: OT: Shouldn't it be `state_info_table[i] = malloc(sizeof(State_t));`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to masquerade the global state_info_table-variable with a local one in create_state_table?

Perhaps it shoult be:
*state_info_table = (State_t *)malloc(state_table_size *sizeof(State_t*));

Comment: That was a desperate and now that i realize a stupid attempt,intially i had the array declared globally as :
State* state_info_table[state_table_size] ={0};

Comment: That would declare a global array of NULL-pointers. Was that your intention?

Comment: By the way: Your loop contains a memory leak. The malloc will request some memory and the pointer to the new allocated memory is stored in state_info_table[i] which is the only way to access the memory. Then you overwrite the only (!) pointer to the memory. You will not be able to access or to delete the memory properly. This is called a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

at you application code declare it with extern as below

```
extern State_t **state_info_table;
```

should work !!